# Expo eas retrieve app archive download url

Tags: expo

After migrating from `expo-cli` to `eas-cli`, I make the app build by using command `eas build -p android`.

Then, in order to be able to use it within my custom CI, I get the app archive download url. I used to use `expo url:apk`. This command is not working anymore, since I make the build with `eas`.

Does anyone know how to get the download url using `eas`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
eas build:list --json --limit=1 --platform=android | jq '.[0].artifacts.buildUrl'
```